# is there any control like treeview in xcode ? and if it possible so give me example

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4, ios-simulator

Is there any control like treeview, then please give me the demo code for it and how to design tree structure - such as parent node, root node etc.

```
Parent1
      Root 1
      Root 2
      Root 3
Parent2
      Root 1
      Root 2
      Root 3
```

And I want check box near all node,

Is this possible to show easily in iPad application?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: how will it look like then? the UI?

Comment: parent-1
   child-1
   child-2
   child-3
 Parent-2
   child-1
   child-2

Comment: You'll have to roll out your own solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to roll out your own solution as in my comment. And just to point you to an identical open source control that exists as per your requirements, there is [this](https://github.com/serverdensity/ios-SDNestedTable) . You might want to play with that and tweak it to your requirements rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: Thanks Bourne,    
 i try my level best. i think this is useful for me.. thanks again